# How to join two tables getting null entries for rows not matching a certain where clause and providing the sum if the clause matches

Tags: sql, join, group

I have the following two tables in a Firebird 2.5 database:

1. BonPos (named P below) with these relevant columns:
   KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR, BON_ID, GV_TYP
2. BonPos_Ust (named PU below) with these relevant columns:
   Z_KASSE_ID, KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR, BON_ID, POS_BRUTTO

The select shall produce:

1. The sum of PU.POS_BRUTTO for those entries where P.GV_TYP = 14
2. 0/Null for all entries where P.GV_TYP is not 14

My current select:

```
select pu.KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR, SUM(pu.POS_BRUTTO)
from BONPOS_UST pu, BONPOS p
where (pu.Z_KASSE_ID = 'MeineKasse') and
      (pu.KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR = p.KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR) and
      (pu.BON_ID = p.BON_ID) and
      (p.GV_TYP = 14)
group by pu.KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR
order by pu.KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR
```

This produces a list of all brutto sums of all receipts
which have a GV_TYP of 14. But the way group by works for
null values it combines them all in one row.

Any way to avoid this?

Update: tried this join meanwhile:

```
select p.KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR, SUM(pu.POS_BRUTTO)
from KASSE_BONPOS p
left join KASSE_BONPOS_UST pu
on (pu.Z_KASSE_ID = 'MeineKasse') and
   (pu.KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR = p.KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR) and
   (pu.BON_ID = p.BON_ID)
WHERE (p.GV_TYP = 14)
group by p.KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR
order by p.KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR
```

But this only produces a list of all KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR
where the sum is Null. I'd need the entries with GV_TYP = 14 and
a sum > 0 in between.

Here's some expected sample output:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr><td>KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR</td><td>SUM</td></tr>
  <tr><td>0</td><td>3.000</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>Null</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td><td>Null</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td><td>-5.000</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
</table>
```

```
CREATE TABLE BONPOS (
BON_ID Integer NOT NULL,
POS_ZEILE Integer NOT NULL,
Z_KASSE_ID Varchar(30),
GV_TYP Integer NOT NULL,
KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR Integer);
ALTER TABLE KASSE_BONPOS ADD PRIMARY KEY (BON_ID,POS_ZEILE);
```

And the other table:

```
CREATE TABLE KASSE_BONPOS_UST (
BON_ID KASSE_Integer NOT NULL,
POS_ZEILE Integer NOT NULL,
Z_KASSE_ID Varchar(30),
KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR Integer,
POS_BRUTTO Numeric(15,2));
```

Comment: Joins are since 30 years SQL standard so it is time to use them.

Comment: You are right, but it didn't work for me either. I tried a right join. But I think the group by semantics gets in my way there... Or can you show me how to make it work with a join?

Comment: please add create tables and data for them and wanted resilt all as text and a dbfiddle would also be good

Comment: I'm not sure you if want two rows for the output - one for GV_TYP = 14 and one for GV_TYP <> 14. If you could provide a sample output list that would help. thx

Comment: Table structure?  Sample input?  Expected output???

Comment: I want one output per KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR. It has to be either Null when there is no GV_TYP = 14 for this KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR or the sum of all BONPOS_UST rows where the corresponding BONPOS row has a GV_TYP of 14.

Comment: What exactly does "But the way group by works for null values it combines them all in one row." mean?

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results, ideally an [MCVE] via link to a dbfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working solution:

```
select pu.KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR,
sum(case
    when p.GV_TYP = 14 then pu.POS_BRUTTO 
    else Null 
  end
 ) as Summe
from KASSE_BONPOS_UST pu
  left join KASSE_BONPOS p
  on (pu.Z_KASSE_ID = 'MeineKasse') and
     (pu.KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR = p.KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR) and
     (pu.BON_ID = p.BON_ID)
  group by pu.KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR
  order by pu.KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Z.KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR, Z.sum_brutto 
FROM KASSE_BONPOS_UST X 
LEFT JOIN (
  select pu.KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR, SUM(pu.POS_BRUTTO) as sum_brutto
  from KASSE_BONPOS_UST pu
  JOIN KASSE_BONPOS p ON (pu.KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR = p.KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR) and (pu.BON_ID = p.BON_ID) and (p.GV_TYP = 14) 
  where (pu.Z_KASSE_ID = 'MeineKasse')         
  group by pu.KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR
  order by pu.KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR
) AS Z ON X.KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR = Z.KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR
```

Comment: Thanks for that attempt, but the data delivered is not correct:
1. It deliveres result rows where both columns are NULL
2. And it delivers several rows per KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR. It shall deliver exactly one row per KASSENABSCHLUSS_NR, which either contains NULL or if there are BONPOS rows with GV_YTP = 14 the sum of BONPOS_UST.POS_BRUTTO

Comment: " It deliveres result rows where both columns are NULL" -- I don't know what both columns you are talking about.  It can't be the columns used in the join because the join would not work.